# Given all the primes up to N, calculate the next prime.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Does a formula exist, such that, when we know all the primes less than N, e.g.: 
2,3,5,7,11 we can calculate the next prime, in this case, 13?
Note: while I am ok with using functions such as gcd(), I am looking for 1 formula, not an algorithm.

Comment: No, no such formula is known, nor expected.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok, thanks for the help!

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [formulas for primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, such a formula would only be of theoretical interest. For practial purposes, it would be utterly useless.

Nearest to what is desired is a recursive formula given in Wikipedia under prime formulas that actually allows to calculate the $n$ th prime knowing all smaller primes with the catch, that the initial value must be known with higher and higher precision. Since no fixed constant does the job in every case, this formula in the strict sense does not qualify.

So I think, we can safely assume that there is no formula for the $n$ th prime, even if we know all smaller primes , although noone can completely rule it out. And as already said, to determine the next prime after the largest we are given, we would anyway choose other algorithms to calculate it, which would be much more efficient.